# Three Tables in Landscape model at equal distance from each other and the margins

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, margins, landscape, vspace

I have the following code:

```
\afterpage{%
\clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
\thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
\begin{landscape}% Landscape page
    \begin{table}
        \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{}
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=20cm}
            \tiny
            \begin{tabular}{|| c | c ||} 
                \hline
                \textbf{DATABASE} & \textbf{QUERY 1: QUERY USED PER DATABASE} \\ [0.5ex] 
                \hline
                Scopus & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                EBSCO/CJA & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                CA/WoS & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ProQuest/IBSS & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                EBSCO/PsycINFO & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ProQuest/CJD & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ScienceDirect & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                Wiley & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                JSTOR & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                WorldCat & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \bigskip
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=20cm}
            \tiny
            \begin{tabular}{|| c | c ||} 
                \hline
                \textbf{DATABASE} & \textbf{QUERY 2: QUERY USED PER DATABASE} \\ [0.5ex] 
                \hline
                Scopus & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                EBSCO/CJA & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                CA/WoS & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ProQuest/IBSS & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                EBSCO/PsycINFO & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ProQuest/CJD & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ScienceDirect & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                Wiley & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                JSTOR & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                WorldCat & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \bigskip
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=20cm}
            \tiny
            \begin{tabular}{|| c | c ||} 
                \hline
                \textbf{DATABASE} & \textbf{QUERY 3: QUERY USED PER DATABASE} \\ [0.5ex] 
                \hline
                Scopus & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                EBSCO/CJA & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                CA/WoS & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ProQuest/IBSS & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                EBSCO/PsycINFO & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ProQuest/CJD & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ScienceDirect & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                Wiley & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                JSTOR & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                WorldCat & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \end{adjustwidth}
        \label{table:3}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\clearpage% Flush page
```

}

Which yields me the following picture:

[image]

Is there away to get rid of the bigger top margin? I have used \vspace and \vspace* in multiple ways but it doesn't help and messes up the landscape mode (its in a normal mode document)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: From the screenshot it seems as if your three table are simply too tall for the page. I guess, you get a warning about this such as "Float too large for page by ...pt". In order to verify this guess and to test suggestions, a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be really helpful. Could you prepare one and include it in your question?

Comment: Since all three tables currently are basically identical and since all querries for all databses inside of one table are also identical, I assume, they are just some sort of placeholder text, that you want to substitute for actual contents later on. Is that correct? If so, are thouse placeholder texts representative for the text length you want to add later?

Comment: Would showing the three tables in aportrait orientation also be an option for you?

Comment: @leandriis Yes they are place holder texts but they will be virtually identical to eachother (some database requires different booleans, that is what I am making clear in these tables)

Comment: @leandriis Thats is not an option unfortunately

Comment: (you don't need the `\afterpage{\clearpage`, as `landscape` implies `\clearpage`   already.  `\vspace*{-1cm}` as the first thing after `\begin{table}` should move everything up by 1cm, hard to debug why that did not work as you did not show what you did or what error you got.

Comment: avoid scaling tables  `\begin{adjustbox}{width=20cm} \tiny`  the `\tiny`  is essentially useless here and the adjustbox will force inconsistent font sizes and rule widths, especially doing this three times in the table will make tables visibly inconsistent with each other.

Comment: How to make sure your three tables fit into the available space depends on a lot of factors, some of them being the documentclass, font and margin sizes. Therefore, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) inclusing the docuentclass as well as the *relevant*  packages and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `geometry` : `\newgeometry` beginning a single page plus `\restoregeometry` at the end.

(1) There is no need to change the font size.

(2) Note the empty line before each `\bigskip`.

(3) Added some vertical stretching of the cells (from `array`).

[image: xc]

[image: w]

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[margin=2in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{pdflscape}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\RequirePackage{array}  

\RequirePackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}
    
1. \kant[1-3]

\afterpage{%
    \newgeometry{margin=0.5in}  
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
        \begin{table}
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
            \centering
            %        \begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{}
            %        \begin{adjustbox}{width=20cm}
            %            \tiny
            \begin{tabular}{|| c | c ||} 
                \hline
                \textbf{DATABASE 1} & \textbf{QUERY 1: QUERY USED PER DATABASE} \\ [0.5ex] 
                \hline
                Scopus & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                EBSCO/CJA & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                CA/WoS & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ProQuest/IBSS & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                EBSCO/PsycINFO & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ProQuest/CJD & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ScienceDirect & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                Wiley & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                JSTOR & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                WorldCat & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            %        \end{adjustbox}
            
            \bigskip
            %        \begin{adjustbox}{width=20cm}
            %            \tiny
            \begin{tabular}{|| c | c ||} 
                \hline
                \textbf{DATABASE 2} & \textbf{QUERY 2: QUERY USED PER DATABASE} \\ [0.5ex] 
                \hline
                Scopus & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                EBSCO/CJA & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                CA/WoS & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ProQuest/IBSS & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                EBSCO/PsycINFO & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ProQuest/CJD & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ScienceDirect & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                Wiley & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                JSTOR & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                WorldCat & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            %        \end{adjustbox}
            
            \bigskip
            %        \begin{adjustbox}{width=20cm}
            %            \tiny
            \begin{tabular}{|| c | c ||} 
                \hline
                \textbf{DATABASE 3} & \textbf{QUERY 3: QUERY USED PER DATABASE} \\ [0.5ex] 
                \hline
                Scopus & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                EBSCO/CJA & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                CA/WoS & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ProQuest/IBSS & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                EBSCO/PsycINFO & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ProQuest/CJD & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                ScienceDirect & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                Wiley & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                JSTOR & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
                WorldCat & (“police” OR “law enforcement”) AND (“response time?” OR “arrival time?”) \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
            %        \end{adjustbox}
            %        \end{adjustwidth}
            \label{table:3}
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\clearpage% Flush page
}

\restoregeometry

2. \kant[2-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. I like "(3) Added some vertical stretching of the cells (from array)." However, since I changed to input the row is now too long for the page. Do you have a tip how to make a line in the table use two rows instead of going off page? @Simon Dispa

Comment: @TimVerlaan you have used `c` which is single line, use `p{5cm}` or whatever width is suitable then it will wrap to that width, or keep it single line but use a smaller font such as `\small` before the tabular.

Comment: Or remove  `\arraystretch`. Maximum width for p column around `p{8in}`

Comment: @TimVerlaan There is a limit in the amount of legible text you can put in a single page.:-). Thank for your feedback.